# Port Forwarding for web hosting

Tags: apache, webserver, port

I just got a raspberry pi for Christmas and I have just installed apache, php and all the required stuff to host my website. I want to use my raspberry pi as a web server for my website. I obviously need to port forward! Apache is running on port 80 how safe is it to forward port 80? I want to know if I port forward is my whole Wi-Fi now under threat from hackers ? If I am hacked, what can they compromise ? And finally I heard about changing the apache port to stop malicious bot port scanners, can I just change my port from 80 to anything or are there only certain ports ?

Thanks, Jamie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is: if you want people's web browser to access your web app, it needs to be on standard ports (80 or 443 for HTTPS). You'll need to redirect connections to ports 80 and/or 443 on your raspberry pi ' local ip in the configuration of your router.

If you want to isolate your raspberry pi from the rest of your local network and that your router allow it, consider putting it in a [dmz](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing))

Even if you were to redirect on a custom ports later to be listened to by Apache, it wouldn't change much in such a case. If you want to secure your server, there is several other options to consider ([fail2ban](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/using-fail2ban-for-security/), firewall rules, etc).

Last: from personal experience, raspberry pis make good web servers to experiment with. Have a lot of nerdy fun

Comment: Okay, thanks so much! How dangerous is port forwarding? And if I port forward, port 80 on my raspberry pi in my router rules does this open port 80 for all devices or just my raspberry pi? Finally will it just be my raspberry pi under threat from attacks (this is fine I just don’t want my whole internet to be under threat)? Sorry for all the Q’s ahah

Comment: It redirects only to your raspberry, that's the point. It means that, from the perspective of the external world, your_public_ip:80 is the port 80 of your raspberry

Comment: Oh okay! Will my pi be okay without a DMZ or is it best to use one ? Thanks so much for the feedback! Merry Xmas

Comment: Merry Xmas. A nice gift would be a plus for my answer (triangle up) ;-p

Comment: Ahah I would but my reputation is below 15, sorry ahah

Comment: @Jami-p42 Right. Do you have enough points to say that the answer solve your problem (the  symbol)?

Comment: I only have 9 ahah, where do I find the button ? I can only see a star for favourite ?

Comment: Between the triangle up and the triangle down